# Error: failed to start container " executable file not found in $PATH: unknown"

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am very new to docker Kubernetes. I have made my cluster of 3 nodes now I am creating a YAML file for pod creation. I have taken the image from https://github.com/utkudarilmaz/docker-hping3 the image name is utkudarilmaz/hping3. Can someone help me to set the command or the docker file in the path? because I cannot understand the problem. I want to run my pod successfully working so, that I can utilize it.
My YAML file like

```
---
 apiVersion: v1
 kind: Pod
 metadata:
   name: second
   labels:
     app: web
 spec:
   containers:
     - name:  hping3
       image: utkudarilmaz/hping3
       command: ["hping3 [IP_ADDRESS"]
       ports:
         - containerPort: 80
   nodeSelector:
       disktype: ssd
```

if I do not specify [command] my pod status is CrashLoopBackOff. I have searched and found that [My kubernetes pods keep crashing with "CrashLoopBackOff" but I can't find any log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41604499/my-kubernetes-pods-keep-crashing-with-crashloopbackoff-but-i-cant-find-any-lo)
I need a command to run the container continuously otherwise it goes in the cycle if I specify a command in YAML file like an above command: ["hping3 103.22.221.59"] and then when I run

```
kubectl exec –it second – hping3 [IP_ADDRESS]
```

I get

```
error: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("hping3")
```

the output of kubectl decribe pod second

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  3m39s                 default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/second1 to netcs
  Normal   Pulled     3m35s                 kubelet            Successfully pulled image "utkudarilmaz/hping3" in 2.714028668s
  Normal   Pulled     3m31s                 kubelet            Successfully pulled image "utkudarilmaz/hping3" in 2.734426606s
  Normal   Pulled     3m15s                 kubelet            Successfully pulled image "utkudarilmaz/hping3" in 2.61256593s
  Normal   Pulled     2m46s                 kubelet            Successfully pulled image "utkudarilmaz/hping3" in 2.65727147s
  Warning  BackOff    2m11s (x5 over 3m4s)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
  Normal   Pulling    2m4s (x5 over 3m38s)  kubelet            Pulling image "utkudarilmaz/hping3"
  Normal   Created    119s (x5 over 3m35s)  kubelet            Created container hping3
Warning  Failed     119s (x5 over 3m35s)  kubelet            Error: failed to start container "hping3": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "hping3 103.22.221.59": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown


  Normal   Pulled     119s                  kubelet            Successfully pulled image "utkudarilmaz/hping3" in 5.128803062s
```

Some Output of docker inspect $utkudarilmaz/hping3

```
"Mounts": [],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "104e9920881b",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": true,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
            ],
            "Cmd": null,
            "Image": "utkudarilmaz/hping3",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "hping3"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "desription": "hping3 tool building on Alpine:latest",
                "version": "1.0"
```

my container will not continue running
when I try this command

```
command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "--" ]
    args: [ "while true; do sleep 30; done;" ] from 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870222/how-can-i-keep-a-container-running-on-kubernetes/40093356
```

same error file not found in the path

Comment: In `command:`, the command name and its arguments need to be separate words; `command: ["hping3", "103.22.221.58"]`.  I wrote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66539524/10008173) a couple of days ago with a longer explanation.

Comment: @david Maze Can we have any generic command which is helpful to just run the container constantly

Comment: What should it _do_?  Think of a container like a process; "can I create a process without specifying a command" isn't really that meaningful, and similarly, just having an empty container sitting around isn't especially useful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870222/how-can-i-keep-a-container-running-on-kubernetes/40093356 like this one but this also not working in my cvase

Comment: I'd expect that should work, yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to specify `containerPort` here as there is nothing listening on any tcp port in your `hping3` container:

```
$ kubectl exec -ti second -- /bin/sh                                                                               
/ # netstat -ntlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
```

In fact you don't even need to provide any `command` as `hping3` is already defined as an `ENTRYPOINT` in this docker image and you don't really need to overwrite it. All you need in order to run your `hping3` `Pod` is the following yaml manifest:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: second
spec:
  containers:
    - name:  hping3
      image: utkudarilmaz/hping3
      args: ["IP-address"]
```

Yes, providing some `args` is obligatory in this case, otherwise your container will fall into `CrashLoopBackOff` state.

As you can read in the very brief description of the image in its [README.md](https://github.com/utkudarilmaz/docker-hping3#docker-hping3):

> **Usage:**
>
> ```
> docker pull utkudarilmaz/hping3:latest
> docker run utkudarilmaz/hping3:latest [parameters] target_ip
> ```

providing `target_ip` is obligatory, but you don't have to provide anything else.

Although the above usage description doesn't say anything about running this image on **kubernetes**, such short description should be totally enough for us and we should be able to translate it "from **docker** to **kubernetes** language".

Take a look at the following section, titled [Define a Command and Arguments for a Container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/), in the official **kubernetes** docs, especially [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#notes) fragment:

> [image]
>
> When you override the default Entrypoint and Cmd, these rules apply:
>
> - If you do not supply  `command`  or  `args`  for a Container, the defaults defined in the Docker image are used.
> - If you supply a  `command`  but no  `args`  for a Container, only the supplied  `command`  is used. The default EntryPoint and the
>   default Cmd defined in the Docker image are ignored.
> - If you supply only  `args`  for a Container, the default Entrypoint defined in the Docker image is run with the  `args`  that
>   you supplied.
> - If you supply a  `command`  and  `args`, the default Entrypoint and the default Cmd defined in the Docker image are ignored. Your
>   `command`  is run with your  `args`.

From the above we are particularly interested in the third point:

> - If you supply only  `args`  for a Container, the default Entrypoint defined in the Docker image is run with the  `args`  that
>   you supplied.

which means that in our **kubernetes** `Pod` definition we may supply only `args` and it's totally fine. As the `ENTRYPOINT` is already defined in the `utkudarilmaz/hping3` image, there is no need to overwrite it by defining a `command`.

I was able to reproduce the error messsage you get only when trying to connect to `hping3` container in `CrashLoopBackOff` state:

```
$ kubectl exec -ti second -- hping3 [IP-address]                                                                  
error: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("hping3")
```

But when it runs, `kubectl exec` works without any issues:

```
$ kubectl exec -ti second -- hping3 [IP-address]
HPING [IP-address] (eth0 [IP-address]): NO FLAGS are set, 40 headers + 0 data bytes
```

Btw. hyphens in your command look a bit strange and they are not exactly the same characters as `-` and are not interpreted correctly when copied from the code snippet in your question, leading to strange errors like the following:

```
Error from server (NotFound): pods "–it" not found
```

So please mind the exact characters that you use in your commands.

As to the explanation of the error message you see when you `kubectl describe` your `Pod`:

```
"hping3 [IP-address]": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

it says clearly that an executable named "hping3 [IP-address]" (yes, name of a single file!) cannot be found in your `$PATH` and I'm sure you don't have executable with such name

If you provide a `command` this way:

```
command: ["hping3 [IP-address]"]
```

keep in mind that the whole string between the double quotes is interpreted as a single command / executable. That's why it was trying to look for executable file named "hping3 [IP-address]" but for obvious reasons it couldn't find it.

As already mentioned in comments, the correct usage of the `command` field can be:

```
command: ["hping3","[IP-address]"]
```

but in your case you don't really need it.

I hope the above explanation was helpful.